# how to force browsers reload static assets after code deployment?

Tags: nginx, varnish

I'm running the following setup: haproxy -> web traffic -> varnish -> nginx (serve static assets) -> node.js (dynamic content) and haproxy -> websockets -> node.js

How can I force browsers to refresh static assets (JavaScript, CSS, ..) after code deployment? (expire/purge the cache?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a querystring to the file with a revision number. Increasing the revision number will force all the assets to come back down to the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js?r=223"></script>
```

Comment: does varnish cache those requests with query strings ?