# how to cache static assets with revision query in URL

Tags: varnish

I want to add a revision number to my static assets so when they're updated browsers will refresh them - [how to force browsers reload static assets after code deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690113/how-to-force-browsers-reload-static-assets-after-code-deployment/14690149?iemail=1#14690149)

Without a revision query string I can see hits in 'varnishstat', with them I see that its passing the request to the backend.

how can I cache static assets with revisions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your static assets regular expression to something like this:

```
if (req.url ~ "\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|swf|js|css)(\?.*|)$") {
  return (lookup);
}
```

it will match revisions too.

Answer (score 0):

It is a strange needs but the following code should resolve your issue :

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|swf|js|css))\?.*$", "\1");
}
```

You will need to clear varnish cache (purge/ban) every time your resource is updated in your backend.

Comment: why is it a strange need ? I want to both cache static assets and make sure the browsers always have the latest version

Comment: E.g. Drupal update static revision number every time you want to clear cache. It will be the case for client's cache but not for drupal's one.